# Can i create sitemap file using pug template? Or can i use pug template to create sitemap file ? I am not using html

Tags: html, node.js, xml, pug, sitemap

Right now i am not using html format create my website. And i have been using pug template with nodejs and express to create a dynamic website for future purposes.

But after uploading the website to serch engine I found out that in order to rank higher in SEO i need a sitemap file but I didn’t knew that and didn’t created it when I launched my website. And l.....

I cannot create sitemap file because i am using pug template with nodejs. And that is the reason that i cannot use html or xml format.....

Sooo can i create sitemap file using pug template in nodejs or not????

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you actually are using HTML to create your site. Pug handles it for you.

To the point of your question: These days, a sitemap is one of the last things you need to worry about, when coding a site, unless it is crucial for you, to have new and updated content indexed asap, and your site has a lot (thousands+) pages. E.g. a news site. In that case, an XML sitemap including priorities and update timestamps of pages might be a good idea. Using Pug to make one would be an option, but any other way of writing XML is too.

Otherwise, make sure your pages are crawlable, interlinked and well structured. In other words, paying attention to content, structure and hierarchy will suffice.